# JavaScript is counting all IMG in all DIVs, need to seperate sliders

Tags: javascript, php

I'm showing multiple clickable images that show a modal/lightbox on click.  Within this modal, I'm calling a slide show.  Those slideshows are showing multiple blank slides.  I have done a console.log on the JS and it seems like it is counting all the IMG tags within all the divs of the class mySlides, and then passing it to the JavaScript.

I'm a complete novice to JavaScript.

Here is the bit of PHP that builds the slideshow.  This is called multiple times on one page.

```
// Slideshow
echo "<div class=\"w3-content w3-display-container\">";

for ( $i = 1; $i <= sizeof($post[$a]['pic']); $i++ ) {

    echo "<img class=\"mySlides\" src=\"".$post[$a]['pic'][$i]."\" style=\"width:100%\">";

}

echo "<button class=\"w3-button w3-black w3-display-left\" onclick=\"plusDivs(-1)\">&#10094;</button>
<button class=\"w3-button w3-black w3-display-right\" onclick=\"plusDivs(1)\">&#10095;</button></div>";
// End slideshow
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

You can find an example of it here: trollolol.club

console.log(i) counts from 0 to 13

I was hoping each call to a slideshow will show just the pictures associated with the given gallery.

Comment: you will generally find it easier to assign event listeners globally rather than inline. If needs be register the event handler on the parent element and use `event delegation` to determine if to proceed

Comment: Are the images local or are they being pulled from somewhere, API, database, etc. ?